# Call javascript function inside erb tag

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, function, erb

I'm trying to add rows to a table as shown in the below code snippet from my view.html.erb file:

```
<% @res.each do |r| %>
    <tr>
        <td class="alt" id="resName"><%= r.name %></td>
        <td class="norm" id="startDate"><%= r.startDate %></td>
        <td class="norm" id="endDate"  ><%= r.endDate %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

The problem that I am encountering is that the startDate and endDate values are being displayed with the format: Thu May 01 2014 08:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT) where I want to display them with the format 05/01/2014.

I have a javascript function, formatDate, which will make the formatting change, but I can't figure out a way to call it from within the erb tags.

I've tried a few things, but can't seem to get it to work. Is it not possible, or am I just doing something wrong? Can anyone offer any help/advice? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<td><%= r.startDate.strftime("%-m/%-d/%Y)" %></td>
```

I prefer very light views; I'd use a decorator:

```
<td><%= r.start_date_formatter %></td>
```

Or at least a helper:

```
<td><%= view_date(r.start_date) %></td>
```

*(Unrelated markup elided for clarity; consider doing the same in future questions. If it's not directly related to the question, it's just noise :)*

Comment: You're missing a quotation mark in the first example. When I tried the first one I got the following error: 'undefined method `strftime' for "Thu May 01 2014 08:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)":String'

After a teeny little bit of Googling found the following code which works perfectly: 'Date.parse(r.startDate).strftime("%-m/%-d/%Y")'

Thank you for your help Dave!

Comment: @George Then you're already doing some processing somewhere, e.g., you're not passing a date to the view layer. That seems weird, since I don't know why you wouldn't store a date as a date in the model. Also note that canonical Ruby and Rails would name those fields `start_date` and `end_date`. I recommend sticking to conventions, especially when starting out.

Comment: I guess the bigger question here is, why isn't that a `datetime` at this point?  You've already run `to_s` on it somewhere.  You shouldn't have to parse it first to format it, it should already be a `Date`.

Comment: @Dave - The dates are stored in the database as strings and I cannot change that unfortunately. It was explained to me a while ago why the dates were being stored as strings, but I can't remember exactly what the reasoning was. Also, the field names (startDate & endDate) are defined in the database.

Comment: @George The Ruby AR class names can be changed to be correct even if the DB names are wrong according to Rails standards. No good reason to store a date as a string, but hey.